# iCloud Drive, How to check iCloud available storage?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, icloud

I am building a document storage app. I am using iCloud Drive to store and sync data across devices. I am using UbiquityContainerIdentifier to get iCloud URL and NSMetadataQuery to sync data. Everything works fine but I had following doubts using iCloud drive:

1. What happens to the data if iCloud storage gets full ?
2. How to know if user's iCloud storage is full ?
3. I have tested my app with a full iCloud storage and it continues to upload data. My data contains text and some images encoded in a json file. I don't want user to loose their data in any condition. So I want to know is there any chance in the future where my files get deleted from iCloud if I continue to save data with iCloud storage full ?